# Change argument inside the state's array, depending on index (React)

Tags: reactjs, state

I've got such state. **citizensData** consists of 20 objects

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...
      data: {
        ...
        ,
        citizensData: [
          {
            id: 1,
            value1: 0,
            value2: 0,
            personalResult: 0
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            value1: 0,
            value2: 0,
            personalResult: 0
          },
          ...
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

I tried to write something like this

```
changeValueHandle = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      data:
      {
        citizensData: [
          {
            value1: event.target.id === this.state.data.citizensData.id
                        ? event.target.value1
                        : 0,
            value2:  event.target.id === this.state.data.citizensData.id
                        ? event.target.value2
                        : 0
          }
        ]
      }
    });
  }
```

but it didn't work (obviously). This method is called inside the component.
This is the main problem for me now. I'm stuck with the problem of changing values depending on their indexes.
The idea is I've got 20 input fields and when I change their values, it should rewrite **personalResult** for exact object inside **citizensData** array.
What is the best and correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.prototype.map and the item id in the change event to indicate what item needs to be changed:

```js
const Item = React.memo(function Item({ change, item }) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) =>
          change(item.id, 'value1', e.target.value)
        }
        value={item.value1}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) =>
          change(item.id, 'value2', e.target.value)
        }
        value={item.value2}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
});
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {
        citizensData: [
          {
            id: 1,
            value1: 'val1',
            value2: 'val2',
            personalResult: 0,
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            value1: 0,
            value2: 0,
            personalResult: 0,
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  }
  changeById = (id, key, value) => {
    this.setState({
      data: {
        ...this.state.data,
        citizensData: this.state.data.citizensData.map(
          (item) =>
            item.id === id
              ? { ...item, [key]: value }
              : item
        ),
      },
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.data.citizensData.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <Item item={item} change={this.changeById} />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```